# How to add GitLab Runner

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, git-log

I Upload GitLab on my server, Now I want to add **GitLab Runner** But when I try to add there is error

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed    runner=zcy-FDTo status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.mysite.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab.mysite.com/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
    PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

What is problem ? i try

```
sudo gitlab-runner register --url https://gitlab.mysite.com/ --registration-token -AMfssacrqy_UeFM4i9pb--
```

Answer (score 1):

I just started learning about Gitlab Runner and stumbled upon your question.
I would suggest to check your hosts network connectivity and certificate setup as your error (x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) indicates, according to [Gitab Runner troubleshooting guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/#im-seeing-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority).